# ngresource open item in new page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ngresource

I created a Rest API in Nodejs and Angular.

In my Angular app i got:

```
app.factory('User', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/users/:id', { id: '@_id' });
});


app.controller("myctrl", function($scope, $http, UserService, $location ){
    $scope.users = User.query();
       $scope.getData = function(userID){
          $location.absUrl("/api/students/"+userID);
       }
  });
```

In nodejs :

```
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
```

I am able to list all the required information. Now i want to have the user opened in a new page. So when I click the user, i have:

**EDIT:**

```
<base href="/">  //in my html head
<p><ng-click="getData(user.id)">username</p>
```

When clicked on username, nothing happens. No error in console log also.

**EDIT**

`$location.url("/api/students/"+userID);` puts the proper location in the address bar but the page stays the same. So I used

```
$window.location.assign("/api/students/"+userID);
```

I'm not sure if I should be using `$window.location.assign`. This works and I get all the proper details. The only problem now is that its all in `JSON`. How and where do I use angular {{}} to show the data? Plus I also want to add some custom html in that output.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use target blank in your `a` tag. In addition to that you will need to inject $location or just use window.location to get the full path, otheriwse the link won't work.

So long story short:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
  
  $scope.userID = 10;
  $scope.baseUrl = $location.protocol() + "://" + $location.host() + ":" + $location.port();
  
  $scope.fullUrl = $scope.baseUrl + '/api/students/' +  $scope.userID;
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello!</p>
    
    <a target="_blank" href="{{baseUrl + '/api/students/' +  userID}}" >Go to new window</a>
    <br/>
    <a target="_blank" href="{{fullUrl}}" >Go to new window</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

And a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uc85OPHhqBxiQ0jwFr7N?p=preview) just in case.

Comment: It says: `Cannot GET /newpage/id=58`  How do i add the route to `newpage/id` in nodejs server?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention you have to put full url in there instead of just that part, use $location.absUrl()

Comment: Still not able to wrap my head around this. Could you please show me an example please. I edited the question. Please check.

Comment: Yeah sure, just wait till I go back home

Comment: Hi @Yaser, tried this but still not working. say i want to include a modal, how do i pass the dynamic data in modal?

Comment: Well that's a completely different question